# azurerm_virtual_machine does not have attribute identity.0.principal_id

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

tf 0.11.11 and 
azurerm 0.31.0

I have been having a go at this for some time now but I am missing something.

I spun up a handful of azurerm_virtual_machine resources without the identity{} block.
After the machines are up, I wanted to add one:

### ./modules/linux/main.tf

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "instance" {
  count                 = "${length(compact(var.hosts))}"

  name                  = "${var.hosts[count.index]}"
  location              = "${data.azurerm_resource_group.instance.location}"
  resource_group_name   = "${data.azurerm_resource_group.instance.name}"

  identity {
    type  = "SystemAssigned"
  }
}

output "system_assigned_identity_principal_ids" {
  value       = "${azurerm_virtual_machine.instance.*.identity.0.principal_id}"
  depends_on  = [ "azurerm_virtual_machine.instance" ]
}
```

### ./main.tf

```
module "linuxvm" {
  source = "./modules/linux"

  hosts = [ "${var.hostnames}" ]
  resource_group_name = "${module.sample_resource_group.name}"
  resource_tags = "${var.resource_tags}"
}
```

During terraform plan, I am getting this error:
Error: Error running plan: 1 error(s) occurred:

```
* module.linuxvm.output.system_assigned_identity_principal_ids: Resource
'azurerm_virtual_machine.instance' does not have attribute 
'identity.0.principal_id' for variable 
'azurerm_virtual_machine.instance.*.identity.0.principal_id'
```

in the state file, there are no other identity attributes (which is expected). The vm's were first created without the identity block.

```
[user@host test]$ terraform show | grep iden
  identity.# = 0
  identity.# = 0
  identity.# = 0
```

If I create vms from scratch, I don't see this issue at all
If I comment out the output block, terraform plan goes through.
I ran out of things to try at this point.

**edit:**
I have another observation. If I change the output from:

```
azurerm_virtual_machine.instance.*.identity.0.principal_id
```

to:

```
azurerm_virtual_machine.instance.0.identity.0.principal_id
```

terraform plan goes through. I have 3 hosts, 0-2 goes through, but using splat wouldn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, when you create the VMs through Terraform with identity enabled, you cannot output the identity Ids if the VMs. Terraform only exports the VM ID, so you just can output the VM ID. See the [VM Attributes](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/virtual_machine.html#attributes-reference).

The command `terraform plan` simply check the grammar of your terraform file. So you cannot output the VM identity Id through Terraform. But you can use the help of Azure CLI or Azure PowerShell. For example, you can use the Azure CLI command like this:

```
resource "null_resource" "output" {
    provisioner "local-exec" {
        command = "az vm show --ids  ${azurerm_virtual_machine.main.id} --query identity.principalId"
    }
}
```

Then the output like this:

[image]

Hope it helps!

**Update:**

The `null_resource` only can output the result but cannot pass the result to other resources as a variable. But you can use the Terraform Data Source to pass the result of the script to other resources as a variable. Here is the example:

script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

eval "$(jq -r '@sh "ids=\(.ids)"')"
identity_id=$(az vm show --ids $ids --query identity.principalId -o tsv)
echo -e "{\"identity\":\"$identity_id\"}"
```

main.tf

```
data "azurerm_virtual_machine" "vm" {
    name = "vmName"
    resource_group_name = "groupName"
}

data "external" "exmaple" {
    program = ["bash", "script.sh"]

    query = {
        ids = "${data.azurerm_virtual_machine.vm.id}"
    }
}

output "identity_id" {
    value = "${data.external.exmaple.result}"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! care to elaborate more why I cannot see the identities of the vm's? I am able to output the principal_id of the vm's if 1) I spin up a fresh set of vm's with the identity block in the resource right of the bat and 2) if I just added the identity block to a vm resource which does not have it previously, I can output the principal_id by explicit index `azurerm_virtual_machine.instance.0.identity.0.principal_id` instead of using splat `azurerm_virtual_machine.instance.*.identity.0.principal_id`.

Comment: @Eyestrain I don't think you can output the vm identity Id if you try the command `terraform apply` because of the terraform does not export the identity of the VM. Just the plan go through. Please try to apply your terraform script.

Comment: I appreciate your answer but as I mentioned, this is working for me for fresh set of VM's, but not on existing ones spun up without the identity block. Also I needed to pass the output to another resource (keyvault in my case) but with null_resource I can't figure out how I can do that.

Comment: @Eyestrain As I said in the answer. Terraform does not expose the VM identity attribute for Azure. So you cannot pass the VM identity as a variable just through the `azurerm_virtual_machine`. I have updated the answer to show you how to pass the VM identity Id as a variable.

Comment: thanks for being patient Charles, I get what you are saying now. The code above works